# Linux headless and mega.nz sync

Tags: linux, sync, headless, xvfb, mega

I have a server with Ubuntu 14.04 and I need to sync (real-time sync, not push-pull via cronjob) with a mega.nz account. Right now my solution was to install Mate and `megasync` gui app, but I want remove the desktop environment. Is there way to use `Xvfb` instead?

I'd also like to have `Xvfb` behave like a service so I can start automatically when system boots up.

Comment: Have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear, I made edit.
I'm stuck at making it service.

Comment: You did edit it and added a tiny bit of context you didn't really improve it. Maybe have a look at [how to ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve it. Right now you're just asking for someone to provide a solution without including any information of what work you've actually done and what you tried. In addition you barely specify why a push/pull wouldn't be sufficient. After all you could use something like [this](https://megatools.megous.com/) in that case. By stating your actual goal maybe alternative solutions could be presented.

Comment: FWIW, this is an open issue with Megatools: https://github.com/megous/megatools/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

Old, but I thought this could use a better answer. MEGA has released an app for that.

[MEGAcmd User Guide](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

**sync**

[Sets up synchronisation between a local folder and one in your MEGA account.](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd/blob/master/UserGuide.md#sync)

Usage:

```
sync [localpath dstremotepath| [-dsr] [ID|localpath]

If no argument is provided, it lists current configured synchronizations

If provided local and remote paths, it will start synchronizing a local folder into a remote folder

If an ID/local path is provided, it will list such synchronization unless an option is specified.

Options:
  -d ID|localpath deletes a synchronization
  -s ID|localpath stops(pauses) a synchronization
  -r ID|localpath resumes a synchronization
  --path-display-size=N  Use a fixed size of N characters for paths

Syncs are associated with your Session, so logging out will cancel them.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of commands you need to run in order to sync desired folder via [megacmd](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd):

First, login:

```
mega-login <email> <pass>
```

Second, setup folder to sync:

```
mega-sync /<local_folder> <remote_path>/<of_some>/<mega_folder>
```

Answering your question, to sync all files from mega on your server:

```
mega-sync /<local_folder> /
```

Where `/` denotes root of your mega account's "filesystem".

To autostart, run `mega-cmd-server`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mega's CLI app, **megacmd**, instead. See https://mega.nz/cmd

From the readme:

> MEGAcmd provides non UI access to MEGA services. It intends to offer
>   all the functionality with your MEGA account via commands.
>
> Available packages for MEGAcmd in all supported platforms should be
>   found here.
>
> It supports 2 modes of interaction:
>
> interactive. A shell to query your actions scriptable. A way to
>   execute commands from a shell/a script/another program. In order to
>   provide those 2 modes, it features one server (MEGAcmdServer), an
>   interactive shell (MEGAcmdShell) and several commands that will launch
>   the non-interactive client (MEGAcmdClient). See Usage and Platform to
>   understand how to use it in your particular system.

Comment: Can you go into some more detail on how to use this application? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].